# How to set innertext of XMLNode to empty string?

Tags: xsd, xmlnode

I have an xsd-generated class from a rich-text field as follows:

```
public partial class Rejection_Reason {

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlNode[] Any;
}
```

Note that the class is generated as an array of XMLNode (not sure why?).   The value is set to null and anytime I attempt to set the innertext of Any[0], a nullreference exception occurs.    How can I set the value of my Rejection Reason class?

I have tried:

```
Rejection_Reason rej = new Rejection_Reason();
XmlNode[] en = rej.Any;
en[0].InnerText = "";
```

But this returns null reference exception when accessing en[0].InnerText

Comment: You need to do this: rej.Any = new XmlNode[] { doc.CreateTextNode("")}; where doc is an XmlDocument you've created somewhere else.